# How can you tell programmatically if a Flex App is running in debug mode?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, debugging

Is it possible to write code in a Flex application that will only be run in a debug build, or when running through the debugger?
Does Flex provide a way to actually remove code entirely from release builds, like C-style #defines?

The app is not necessarily running in a web page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do conditional compilation like this:

```
CONFIG::debugging {
    // this will be removed if CONFIG::debugging resolves to false at compile time
}
```

And then add this to the compiler flags:

```
-define+=CONFIG::debugging,true
```

for debug builds, and

```
-define+=CONFIG::debugging,false
```

for release builds. `CONFIG` and `debugging` can be anything, like `MY_AWESOME_NAMESPACE` and `fooBar`, it doesn't matter.

Read more here: [Using conditional compilation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html).

Comment: There is the static property `Capabilities.isDebugger` in the [flash.system.Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#isDebugger) class, but I don't recommend using this to target the debug Flash player since you can't assume that users won't have the debug player installed. Conditional compiling is the way to go if you want to create your own special builds.